# O que significa A solução faz comparações contra strings no seguinte código? JS

Tags: javascript, string, comparação

**O enunciado do exercício é**: Declare a variável diaDeSemana que receba uma string "domingo". Depois implemente uma condicional usando o if que compare se diaDeSemana é igual a "domingo", se for verdadeiro imprima uma string "Hoje é dia de futebol!!!".

**Eu fiz o seguinte código:**

```
var diaDeSemana = "domingo";

if ( "domingo" === diaDeSemana) {

  console.log("hoje é dia de futebol!");

}
```

A solução é aceita, mas aparece o aviso que a mesma faz comparação contra strings! Já pesquisei na internet sobre as diferentes formas de comparação, mas nao achei nenhum resultado para esse erro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O que fizeste está certo. Não vejo necessidade de comparar de outra maneira num exercício senão algures teres uma string.

O que podes fazer é declarar a resposta certa também numa variável e depois comparar essas variáveis. Isso usa-se por vezes quando o servidor é quem dá a resposta certa numa variável do `fetch`.

Por exemplo:

```js
const RESPOSTA_CERTA = 'domingo';

function oQueFazerHoje(diaDeSemana) {
  if (diaDeSemana === RESPOSTA_CERTA) return 'hoje é dia de futebol!';
}

console.log(oQueFazerHoje('domingo'));
```

No trabalho usamos muito a prática de declarar variáveis de strings estáticas/constantes em letras maiúsculas para ser claro para o programador que está a usar uma constante. Para além de evitar erros, é também boa prática para não escrever a mesta string várias vezes em variáveis diferentes... Criei até [uma ferramenta para mudar o javaScript](https://github.com/SergioCrisostomo/vue-codemods) e fazer isso no código automaticamente.

Comment: será que é isso? vou testar e ja volto pra te dar o retorno!

Comment: Sergio, vc esta certo! Declarei a resposta como variavel e depois comparei as duas variaveis

Comment: @StéphanieVerissimo ótimo!

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi este problema da seguinte forma:

```
var diaDeSemana = "domingo";

var dia = 'domingo';

if (diaDeSemana == dia)

{
  console.log("Hoje é dia de futebol!!!");
}
```

sem apresentar a mensagem de erro!

Answer (score 0):

Estou refazendo o exercício e encontrei esta solução:

```
var diaCerto = "domingo"
var diaDeSemana = diaCerto

if(diaDeSemana == diaCerto){
  console.log("Hoje é dia de futebol!!!")
}
```

Comment: Isso não é uma solução, vai dizer que é dia de futebol para qualquer coisa que puser na string. Em parte a culpa é do lugar que te passou o exercício duvidoso. Posso estar enganado, mas me dá a forte impressão de ser uma fonte de estudos muito ruim, sugiro cautela.

Comment: é verdade, obrigada pelo conselho.

Comment: De qualquer forma, a resposta que você marcou como escolhida, do @Sergio, é a mais adequada de tudo que foi postado até então. Bons estudos.

Answer (score -1):

```
var diaDeSemana = "domingo";    
var valorComparativo = "domingo";    
if (diaDeSemana === valorComparativo) {    
  console.log("hoje é dia de futebol!");    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var diaDeSemana = "domingo";
var dia = 'domingo';
if ( diaDeSemana === dia) {

  console.log("hoje é dia de futebol!");

}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
let diaDeSemana = "domingo"

let dia = "domingo"

if (diaDeSemana == dia)

{
  console.log("Hoje é dia de futebol!!!");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
var diaDeSemana = "domingo";

if ( diaDeSemana = "domingo" ) {

  console.log("hoje é dia de futebol!");

}
```

Dessa forma e a correta domingo esta sendo atribuída ao dia da semana, ele não pode ser comparado, pois sabemos que ele já é um dia da semana.