# Como faço uma função com if/else?

Tags: javascript

Escrevi essa função mais dá erro e gostaria de entender por que:

```
function hojeSeJoga (domingo){
  if (domingo==domingo){
    console.log("Hoje é dia de futebol")
    return true;
    } else{
      console.log("Hoje não é dia de futebol")
      return false;
      } 
  }
```

Comment: Você pretende dizer que se `domingo` for diferente de `domingo` então não é dia de futebol? Algo como `se 1 for diferente de 1`?

Comment: Tente algo do tipo `domingo === 'domingo'`

Comment: E qual o valor que é passado no parametro `hojeSeJoga(valor aqui)`? É uma string ou é um valor numerico, ou uma string em formato de data ou é um objeto de  `new Date`?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar aspas para fazer essa comparação. Também sugiro que mude o nome do parâmetro da função para **dia**:

```js
function hojeSeJoga (dia){
  if (dia=="domingo"){
    console.log("Hoje é dia de futebol")
    return true;
  }else{
    console.log("Hoje não é dia de futebol")
     return false;
    } 
 }
 
 hojeSeJoga('sábado')
 hojeSeJoga('domingo')
```

No seu código original, você não usa aspas, o que faz com que a função ache que o operando à direita do operador de igualdade seja uma variável: dessa forma, a comparação tá sendo se algo é igual a esse algo, ou seja, ele sempre entre no primeiro *if*, independente do valor do argumento passado à função.

Comment: Perfeito! Apenas usaria "===" ;)

Comment: Apareceu isso :  Sua solução não passou as provas
Objetivos que não foram atendidos:
 hojeSeJoga faz comparações contra strings
Resultados do teste:
 hojeSeJoga("domingo") deveria dizer se joga Ver detalhes
true == 'Hoje é dia de futebol!!!'
 hojeSeJoga("terça") devería dizer que não joga Ver detalhes
false == 'Hoje não é dia de futebol!

Comment: @RenanSantos Com todo respeito, mas já perdi as contas de quantas vezes fizeram essa mesma pergunta aqui, bastava fazer uma simples busca, [**veja**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Hoje+%C3%A9+dia+de+futebol) <- sugiro que leia todas elas, pois além de já ter várias respostas (como [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406319/112052), por exemplo), a conclusão que chegamos é que esse site aí não é uma fonte muito boa de estudo, já que esse "erro" de "comparações contra strings" é ridículo, além de desensinar e confundir iniciantes.

Comment: Por exemplo, veja [este comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/424053#comment823456_424053), [esse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/424053#comment825324_424055) e [esse também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/406316#comment848140_439180). Resumindo, a solução acima é perfeitamente válida. Se o site obriga a fazer comparações de outra maneira sem explicar o motivo, não é uma boa fonte de estudos (pois o motivo depende do contexto).